# What's the meaning of the key "previous_timestamp_micros" in the Google Firebase event raw data

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I've exported the Google Firebase events raw data to the Google BigQuery. Each event has four key: `name`, `params`, `timestamp_micros`, `previous_timestamp_micros`. As a example, I past a `session_start` event below which is extracted from my data

```
"event_dim":[
    {"name":"session_start",
     "params":[
         {"key":"firebase_event_origin",
          "value":{"string_value":"auto"}}],
     "timestamp_micros":"1467374617058000",
     "previous_timestamp_micros":"1467191135684000"}, ...]
```

What's the meaning of the key `previous_timestamp_micros`? Is it the timestamp of the previous `session_start` of the same user? Or is it the timestamp of a previous event of the same user? I've checked the data, it seems both guesses are incorrect.

Comment: when you list events by using timestamp there would be repeating column ids, but previous_timestamp adding an additional distinction level, in case when I using "group by function" previous_timestamp help me. Of course there is a risk of repeating but it almost impossible by chance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is from event_dim schema

```
timestamp_micros            INTEGER     The timestamp (in microseconds) at which this  
                                        event was logged.   
previous_timestamp_micros   INTEGER     The timestamp (in microseconds) at which this  
                                        event was previously logged.
```

See more details [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846)

Comment: Is it somehow possible to convert this timestamp in a datetime format?

Comment: yes, but please start a new Stack Overflow question :)

Comment: @tuspazio: use FORMAT_UTC_USEC() in BigQuery.

Comment: As far as I understand, when an event was sent to Firebase second time previous_timestamp_micros shows previous event's date? But when I try to find this event date as timestamp_micros it returns zero result. Why do get this error do you think ? @Mikhail